# string replace left join en el proceso (con R)

Tags: r, condiciones, join, r-dplyr, str-replace

Tengo un data frame que hay que limpiar reemplazando ciertos valores en todas sus variables. La  estructura es:

```
all_data <- data.frame(
  var1 = c('187311','117161','B','A', NA,'D'),
  var2 = c('944545','231354',NA,NA,'A',NA  ),
  var3 = c('944785',NA,'231354','A',NA,'B' ),
  var4 = c(NA,NA,'364829','231354','C','D' ))
```

Todas las variables son de un mismo tipo, vector de carácteres que pueden contener: números, letras sencilla y NA.

- Los string que son números deben de ser reemplazados por los del diccionario
- Los string que son ya una letras sencilla se deberían dejar, ya que están bien etiquetados
- No se hacen cambios tampoco con los NA.

Para reeemplazar las variables mal etiquetadas tengo el diccionario:

```
diccionario <- data.frame(
  wrong_name= c(187311,117161, 944545,231354,944785,231354,364829),
  correct_name= c('F','G','H','I','J','K', 'L' ) )
```

**el resultado debería lucir**:

```
all_data <- data.frame(
  var1 = c('F','G','B','A', NA,'D'),
  var2 = c('H','I',NA,NA,'A',NA  ),
  var3 = c('J',NA,'K','A',NA,'B' ),
  var4 = c(NA,NA,'L','K','C','D' ))
```

aquí dejo un pseudocódigo de lo que he probado con la familia de map y dplyr pero no me da buenos resultados para un proceso así. No es el código completo por que el procedimiento lo he borrado (craso error)

```
all_data %>%
  map(
       ~imap(
    left_join(.x, test, by = 'wrong_name')) %>%
      mutate(F_mal_codificado = str_detect(., pattern="^[[:digit:]]")) %>%
      mutate(farmaco2 = case_when( F_mal_codificado == TRUE ~ correct_name, F_mal_codificado == F ~ farmaco2))) %>%
      select(.y)
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto deberías probarlo con un volumen real de datos, por que básicamente es una función tipo `lookup` para reemplazar un valor por otro. Si bien traté de usar la mejor alternativa posible en cuanto a velocidad (ver [R fast single item lookup from list vs data.table vs hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232865/r-fast-single-item-lookup-from-list-vs-data-table-vs-hash)), habría que comparar su funcionamiento con `dplyr` o incluso `data.table`. La idea como te decía es construir una función de reemplazo, vectorizada para que sea fácil de implementar en un lote de `dplyr`:

```
function_replace_name_constructor <- function(wrong_name_vector) {

  diccionario  <- data.frame(
    wrong_name= c('187311','117161', '944545', '231354', '944785', '231354', '364829'),
    correct_name= c('F','G','H','I','J','K', 'L')
  )
  lookup_list <- list2env(setNames(as.list(1:nrow(diccionario)), diccionario$wrong_name))

  lookup <- function(wrong_name_vector) {
    
    sapply(wrong_name_vector, 
           function(wrong_name) {
              x <- diccionario[lookup_list[[wrong_name]], 'correct_name']
              if (length(x) == 0) return(wrong_name)
              x
           })
  }
  return(lookup)
}

replace_name <- function_replace_name_constructor()
```

Lo único particular, es que uso un patrón de `function factory`, con el objeto de "encapsular" los datos de reemplazo y no tener que pasar estos todo el tiempo por parámetro. La función que retorna `function_replace_name_constructor()` y que llamaremos como `replace_name()` puede usarse directamente con un vector:

```
replace_name(c('187311','117161', '944545', '231354', '944785', '231354', '364829'))

 187311 117161 944545 231354 944785 231354 364829 
   "F"    "G"    "H"    "K"    "J"    "K"    "L"
```

Así, es muy natural su aplicación mediante `dplyr`, imaginando que el reemplazo lo aplicamos a todas las columnas, podemos hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

all_data %>% 
  mutate_all(., replace_name)

  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    F    H    J <NA>
2    G    K <NA> <NA>
3    B <NA>    K    L
4    A <NA>    A    K
5 <NA>    A <NA>    C
6    D <NA>    B    D
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haría sería crear una función que realice los cambios.

```
f1<-function(x){
  x<-ifelse(x=="187311","F",x)
  x<-ifelse(x=="117161","G",x)
  x<-ifelse(x=="944545","H",x)
  x<-ifelse(x=="231354","I",x)
  x<-ifelse(x=="944785","J",x)
  x<-ifelse(x=="231354","K",x)
  x<-ifelse(x=="364829","L",x)
  x
}
```

Como son pocos así lo haría, pero si son muchos con un for también se podría hacer. `En tu código hay distintos valores para el código 231354` Estás asignando `I e K`. Me imagino que es uno distinto. En fin.

El detalle, aquí es que la función se puede aplicar a cada uno de los vectores.

La aplicación sería lo siguiente:

```
all_data %>% mutate_all(list(f1))
```

EL resultado:

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    F    H    J <NA>
2    G    I <NA> <NA>
3    B <NA>    I    L
4    A <NA>    A    I
5 <NA>    A <NA>    C
6    D <NA>    B    D
```